# which methods of Java Vector class are synchronized?

Tags: java, collections

Which of the methods of java Vector class is synchronized.Since there is no explicit synchronized in javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All methods of the Vector class that change the state of the vector are synchronized.

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html.  Scroll down to the method detail section.

Comment: Beware: those are javadocs from the Apache Harmony implementation.

Comment: @Stephen No need to beware. The documentation from Sun says the class is synchronized.  See <http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html> for example.

Comment: @Steve - you miss my point.  It is **bad idea** to use the Apache javadocs to tell you about the Sun APIs ... or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is in the last line of the [class Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html):

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized.

`Vector` is essentially a synchronized [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of explicit statements in the Javadoc, look at the source code.  For instance, you can find them in the `src.zip` file in your JDK installation.

In fact, nearly all methods that access or update the state of the Vector synchronize at some point.  However, the `Iterator` returned by `iterator()` and the `Enumeration` returned by `elements()` only synchronize during next / hasNext calls.